# How do sites that allow you to paste a small javascript script in your html track your site?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

For example google analytics and statscounter allows you to paste a small script in your html which then allows you to track and see your visitors. How does this work? is the script you paste considered an api? what is this process called? How do I go about creating such in rails?

Comment: [site:stackoverflow.com how does google analytics work](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+does+google+analytics+work&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP.

Basically the script you paste in makes an http request to the endpoint specified by it's "src" attribute as the page is loading. This pulls in a javascript file (usually an immediately invoked function) that then executes in the context of your page.